# Trigger function on blur

Tags: jquery, blur

The jQuery blur() function doesnt trigger the function that i want to trigger.

```
        socket.on('new message', function(data){
            $chat.append('<b>' + data.nick + ': </b>' + data.msg + "<br/>");

            document.getElementById("chat").scrollTop = document.getElementById("chat").scrollHeight;      

            $( "#contentWrap" ).blur(function() {
              audioElement.play();
              alert('This works');
              console.log('This works');
            });

        });
```

Why is that the function not work, i just do the same thing what the jQuery site tells.

Comment: What is `socket`, are `new` and `message` *meant* to be two separate events? Does `#contentWrap` exist in the page when the event-handlers are bound, have you wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` (or equivalent)?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the handler/code within `document.ready` event like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#contentWrap" ).blur(function() {
        // code...
    });
});
```